# Where can I find hydroelectric generation data for the U.S.?

Tags: data, hydrology, united-states

It is my understanding that the US Army Corps of Engineers has some hydro generation data on their various websites (divisions, districts). For example, there is real-time hydro-electric data generation for the Tulsa District located here: http://www.swt-wc.usace.army.mil/ops_hydropower/hydromainpage.html. However, other districts do not have this same data. Is there any reason why hydroelectric power generation is only reported in some districts but not others? What is a resource I can use to find real-time (and/or even historical) power generation data for other regions (besides the Tulsa area).

I have scoured every single USACE website for all the regions, have examined the various hydro-electric power administrations in the United States (BPA, TVA, SEPA, WEPA) to little avail. Only BPA contained real-time and historical data. I am especially interested in the southeastern part of the United States - states like TN, GA, AL, etc. Proxy generation (like river/lake levels) may also be useful, but I have not been able to find those aside for the Tulsa/BPA areas.

Are there any other resources for this type of data that I am looking for? Even if it is proprietary that would be fine.

Comment: Some federal agencies leave certain services up to the individual division or district. The individuals may not provide a service due to lack of data availability, resources, budget, or demand for their particular area, whereas another might. For example I know some USFS Ranger districts provide road status pages, whereas others do not. There are some National Park websites that provide certain maps and features, while other parks don't because they're much smaller or simply don't have the number of features or demand for the service to justify them.

Answer (score 1):

The EPA has a [power profiler](http://oaspub.epa.gov/powpro/ept_pack.charts) service that allows you to find out "how clean" the power you are getting is. It profiles the percent of power coming from each type of power generation per zip code. Unfortunately, I cannot find any place to get the data for all zip codes at once. Alternatively, there are [downloadable databases](http://www.epa.gov/cleanenergy/energy-resources/egrid/index.html) that profile power subregions and plants that exist throughout the nation which also profiles power generation, but doesn't tie in to where the power is being used. If you do find other data related to this, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely encounter difficulties obtaining this information due to security concerns. I was looking for some information from the national dam inventory. At the time, the information was on a public facing site but required an ACOE account to access it. I also recall reading a fairly recent article about the NID being hacked, possibly by a foreign government for use in a future cyber attack. I believe what you're finding on the site for individual districts will eventually be removed due to this.

Comment: Looks like they changed it up a bit. According to the NID site, "Non-government users can query the database using the interactive report and map functions but cannot directly download any data from this site".  http://geo.usace.army.mil/pgis/f?p=397:1:0